# Multer destination file is not readable by ZEIT now

Tags: javascript, node.js, vercel

Hi im triying to upload images to cloudinary using multer in my nodejs app it works perfectly on the localhost but when i upload it to zeit it doesn't work it says "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open (folder)"
I tried using @now/static to make the folder available but it doesn't work too. I will be happy if you can help me.

```
const express = require("express")
const multer = require("multer")
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2
const cors = require("cors")

const config = require("../../config")
const response = require("../../network/response")
const Controller = require("./index")
const auth = require("./secure")

const router = express.Router()

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: config.cloudinary.name,
  api_key: config.cloudinary.api_key,
  api_secret: config.cloudinary.api_secret,
})

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./public/uploads")
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  },
})

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 },
})

// Set routes
router.use(cors())
router.get("/", auth("list"), list)
router.post("/", auth("add"), upload.single("file"), upsert)

// Router Functions
function list(req, res, next) {
  Controller.list()
    .then((post) => {
      response.success(req, res, post, 200)
    })
    .catch(next)
}

function upsert(req, res, next) {
  const path = req.file.path
  const uniqueFilename = new Date().toISOString()

  cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    path,
    { public_id: `public/${uniqueFilename}` }, // directory and tags are optional
    function (err, image) {
      if (err) return res.send(err)
      console.log("file uploaded to Cloudinary")
      // remove file from server
      const fs = require("fs")
      fs.unlinkSync(path)
    }
  )

  Controller.upsert(req.body, uniqueFilename)
    .then((post) => {
      response.success(req, res, post, 201)
    })
    .catch(next)
}

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with Zeit/Vercel, your API code runs in a Lambda.
This lambda is meant to be disposable when it finishes executing,
therefore the filesystem that you use in your API is destroyed upon the end of your upload execution.

(it works locally because no one destroys your computer at the end :D).

To get this scenario working, you'll need to write the uploaded file somewhere persistent, such as AWS S3.